# Python - string/regex match

Tags: python, regex, string, match

I am trying to match something like below to match the incoming dynamic API path. It is an exact string compare but the incoming string position respective to wild character `*` should be ignored and be matched as it can be anything.

`/v1/*/test` should match  `/v1/jnjnjnjn/test`
but shouldn't match `/v0/knknkk/test/test`

`/v1/\*/test/\*`  should match  `/v1/niniiuhi/test/njnjnj`
but shouldn't match `/v1/niniiuhi/test/njnjnj/knknkmkm`

I tried the below.

```
re.search('v1/.*/test', 'v1/vhvhv98988/test/test')
```

but it matches for both `v1/njnjnj/test` and also `v1/njnjnj/test/test`.

Any help will be appreciated? Thanks in advance

Comment: It's unclear what the criteria are for when something should match. Please [edit] to indicate *why* the negative example should not match. Trivially, if there is a single string which should be excluded, check that before applying the regex, or add a negative lookahead to the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `*` should match just a single component, we need to exclude `/` from the match, or specifically include those characters that are permitted.

- `re.search(r'^/v1/[^/]*/test$', '/v1/jnjnjnjn/test')` will match anything other than a `/` in the wildcard component.
- `re.search(r'^/v1/[a-z0-9_-]*/test$', '/v1/jnjnjnjn/test')` will match lower-case letters, digits, underscores and dashes in the wildcard component.

Usually the second option tends to be safer, but it does depend on your requirements.

In both cases, you should anchor your search with `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end unless you do want to search for sub-strings.

As a general tool, sites like https://regex101.com/ (there are a bunch of them) can help develop regexes by explaining what's going on and by immediately showing results.